# What is the best book for electrostatics for engineers?

Tags: electrostatics, resource-recommendations, education

Basically, what I want is a book on electrostatics that is **easy to understand**, **for self-study**, and which also teaches the associated calculus, like the different coordinate systems, gradient, curl and divergence, fundamental theorems of integration, etc. I am a sophomore engineering student, and want to properly understand the nuances of electrostatics. Any video-lectures recommendations are also welcome.

Comment: I think Griffiths' textbook on electromagnetism fits the bill perfectly here. Also, on YouTube there are MIT's electromagnetism lectures, by Walter White, which are very helpful for learning alongside/slightly prior to Griffiths

Comment: Take a look at [Engineering Electromagnetics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrPZ1.jpg) by William H.Hayt-John A.Buck.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for exactly the same stuff~
Here is what my research on this led me to.

1. "Introduction to Electrodynamics"- Griffith. [link](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoel0000grif)
   I hate this book, but it is highly popular in the community and a first choice of many. The style is pretty frank and crisp. (Why do I hate it? It just left me with more questions in the end and this justifies the title - an introduction). This book is a great motivational book. (The problems are good.)
2. "Electricity and Magnetism" - Purcell [link](https://archive.org/details/ElectricityAndMagnetismPurcell3rdEdition)
   A bit lighter on the mathematics and (I found) a bit more intuitive than Griffith. I personally would recommend to this book to the fresh eyes of an undergraduate. It offers a high-school-ish approach to the subject.
3. "Elements of Electromagnetism" - Sadiku [link](https://archive.org/details/elementsofelectr0000sadi_d3c6)
   I paired this book with Griffith; never did finish it though. I would say it is "yet another book". I leave the further exploration onto you.

You said specifically "electrostatics", although it is completely a hypothetical setup to transition towards the more useful "electrodynamics"; I give you the benefit of doubt and assure you that it will be included in the recommendations.

A note on the "engineering perspective" of the nature of study that entails.

As engineers, we are not concerned about certain "aspects" that may occur in the discussion of the subject under theoretical physics. However, it could be at your discretion to explore those. But, majority of attention is better spent on practicality of the discussion.

Here is a suggestion of EM books with that engg perspective:-

1. "The Electromagnetic field" - Shadowitz [link](https://archive.org/details/electromagneticf0000shad/page/n18/mode/1up?view=theater) A good book, a quick and objective (yet not shallow) study of the underlying physics with connections made to engineering.
2. "Fundamentals of Engineering Electromagnetics" - Cheng [link](https://archive.org/details/fund-of-eng-elec/page/n17/mode/1up) Crisp, lucid, to the point. We don't delve a lot into the theoretical physics aspect for long, which I see as good. (still might want to pair with one of the above three)

I personally abhor video lectures which is reflected in this answer. You do you.
If ever want to pursue classical electromagnetics beyond this level; Click [this](https://archive.org/details/ClassicalElectrodynamics2nd).
It suffices.